# Adding bottom Toolbar similar to the toolbar on iOS devices

Tags: android

Is there away to add a toolbar on the bottom to Android, similar to the toolbar on iOS devices.?

[image]

Comment: What about a RelativeLayout with some TextViews? 1 TextView in the first image, 3 in the second one.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good idea. I though thee something ready.

Comment: Just fix a widget to the bottom of the screen, perhaps a framelayout or relative layout, there is also a 'split' mode for the ActionBar that will do something similar.

Comment: There's also a Toolbar class that acts as an ActionBar that you can position as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @Egor, do you have a link or an example for this Toolbar class.

Comment: @user836026, not to be rude, but you have a rep score of 1666.  Have you tried google:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=android+toolbar

Comment: @Joe Yes i tried, I notice the toolbar class, but my understanding that only works as topbar. I'm not sure if there is away to make appear on bottom.

Comment: Ok, that is a better question :).  Take a look at @Egor answer.  The tool bar can be used anywhere.  It is just another view.  Here is an article with a bottom toolbar http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use toolbar inside your layout to make your footer as required :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- // Main content comes here  -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add toolbar.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

  <!-- One can customize it as much as he wants, for showing an example,
       I have shown below how to add an image at the center of toolbar-->

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new Android `Toolbar` widget:

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) article provides a pretty good description of how you can use the Toolbar in your app

[Toolbar reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)